# Jmeter Cache manager videos

Tags: jmeter

We want to learn about cache manager how can be used in jmeter.. and cookie manager too.

Comment: First hit in Google: https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager

Comment: I have done it earlier too .. but there is nothing much to tell me how to implment

Comment: you need to asks specific questions: what's not working for you now, and what you want to achieve. Nobody will post a lecture here.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about Cache Manager at:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager
- https://blog.flood.io/understanding-the-jmeter-cache/

And for Cookie Manager:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

To use them, just add them to your Test Plan and configure them as per documentation depending on your test case.